# "Zip App Bundle" missing in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: ios, xamarin

As you can see, the "Zip App Bundle" is not available. I have tied the following to make sure it is available.

1. Solution is in RELEASE
2. All App icons are set
3. Provisioning profiles installed
4. All app properties are set
5. App will build on build server
6. I can build RELEASE
7. "DEVICE" is selected in the attach menu
8. iOS Application sheet in Properties is all filled out

Yet the Zip Bundle is still greyed out???

[image]

Comment: ever figure this one out? i have the same problem

Comment: No, I haven't heard of a fix

Comment: I ended up having to put mine in to Ad-Hoc build profile to get Zip App Bundle... to show. I was then able to use the Application Loader on OSX to upload that bundle.

Answer (score 0):

What Zach Green said in comments.

You have to build your solution in `Ad-Hoc` instead of `Release`, and you need to select `Iphone` as the platform to enable the `Zip App Bundle...` and `Show IPA File on Build Server` commands for the iOS project.